# MySQL deadlock on one table with multithreading code

Tags: mysql, sql, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I've created an application which gathers prices and stores it in a database.
The application runs with two threads. But now and then a deadlock occurs. I think it is because the treads insert a bulk of prices to the same table.

**The table**

`[tripid | date | duration | price | garant | updatetime | persons | accommodationid]`

**The indexes**

`unique (tripid, date, duration, price, persons)
foreign key 'accommodationid' to table 'accommodation.id'`

**The query**

`insert into prices (tripid, date, duration, price, persons, accomodationid)
            values  ( 1 , 2016-6-4, 8, 200,2,32),
                       ... a whole lot more ... 
                    ( 1 , 2016-7-4, 8, 200,2,32)
            on duplicate key update price = values(price);`

Becouse there can be 1000 values to insert in 1 query it takes some time. I think the deadlock occurs when the second thread wants to insert another 1000 values but the first one is not completed.

**The innodb status**

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2016-03-16 23:13:13 0xef8
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3732195928, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 415, OS thread handle 7328, query id 10956855 ---(ip)-- --name-- update
insert into `prices` (tripid,`date`,`duration`,`price`,`garant`,`updatetime`,`persons`,`accommodationid`) values
(179881,'2016-03-18',2,206,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-18',3,260,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-18',4,313,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-18',5,366,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-19',2,206,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-19',3,260,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-19',4,313,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-19',5,366,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-20',2,206,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-20',3,260,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-20',4,313,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-20',5,366,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-21',2,206,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-21',3,260,'0','2016-03-16','1','119'),(179881,'2016-03-21',4,313,
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 247 page no 1457 n bits 136 index keyGroup of table `travel`.`prices` trx id 3732195928 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3732195927, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 4529
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
15 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 476 row lock(s), undo log entries 472
MySQL thread id 414, OS thread handle 3832, query id 10956852 ---(ip)-- --name-- update
insert into `prices` (tripid,`date`,`duration`,`price`,`garant`,`updatetime`,`persons`,`accommodationid`) values
(179880,'2016-03-18',2,185,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-18',3,217,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-18',4,249,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-18',5,279,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-18',6,312,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-18',7,343,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-18',8,375,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-19',2,185,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-19',3,217,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-19',4,249,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-19',5,279,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-19',6,312,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-19',7,343,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016-03-20',2,185,'0','2016-03-16','1','1438'),(179880,'2016
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 247 page no 1457 n bits 72 index keyGroup of table `travel`.`prices` trx id 3732195927 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 247 page no 1457 n bits 136 index keyGroup of table `travel`.`prices` trx id 3732195927 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
------------
```

**The Question**

How do I avoid the deadlock?

Comment: By using a single thread, at least for the inserting/updating.

Comment: The application does a lot more. I can reduce the whole process of calculating prices with 4 hours if I use more threads in the application. So its a little simple to say "use 1 thread" isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it by first locking the table, then do the huge query and unlock it so the second thread gets acces.

```
LOCK TABLES prices WRITE;

insert into prices (tripid, date, duration, price, persons, accomodationid)
            values  ( 1 , 2016-6-4, 8, 200,2,32),
                       ... a whole lot more ... 
                    ( 1 , 2016-7-4, 8, 200,2,32)
            on duplicate key update price = values(price);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Which effectively makes the app single threaded, since, at any time, at most one thread is active, and the other(s) waiting. (convoy lock)

Comment: Well.. that doesn't make the app single threaded, only the execution of this query. The app does tons of other things and once in 10 minutes they execute this query at the same time. So its no problem if one waits for another thread to finish this query.